# Berry phase for instanton events in 2d quantum antiferromagnet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am reading the paper "http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.1029" by Haldane where he calculates the berry phase associated with instanton or hedgehog events in the O(3) nonlinear sigma model (described by the unit vectors $\Omega(x,y,t)$). On page 2 last paragraph he says that a hedghog event will create $\pm 4 \pi$ vortex of$w(x,y)$ at the spatial centre of the hedghog, where $w(x,y)$ is supposed to be the berry phase obtained by the closed loop defined by the time evolution of $\Omega(x,y,t)$. I am confused by this statement, because after the hedghog event, the initial field configuration has changed to a configuration with a different skyrmion number and $\Omega(x,y,t)$ does not 
define a closed loop. So,I don't understand what did he mean by $w(x,y)$ in this case. If somebody can clarify this, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Even if $\Omega(x,y,t)$ does not form a closed loop on the unit sphere you can still integrate the berry phase term to yield something purely geometric no?

Comment: That is true. But he actually says (at the beginning of page-3) that "[Consider a point $r$ near the spatial center of the hedgehog, and study how the closed path on the sphere defined by the time variation of $\Omega(r,t)$ varies as $r$ is moved once around the hedgehog: the only significant variation occurs during the time interval when tunneling occurs, hence the change in $w$ is obtained from the behavior of $\Omega$ near the hedgehog.]"  This actually added to my confusion.

Comment: I am also confused by some statements in this paper, for example about the tunneling process. He defined the tunneling process as skyrmion number changed by $\pm 1$, if the initial configuration has 1, is it possible to have 2 after the instanton event ?

Comment: "The time variation of Ω(,) varies as  is moved once around the hedgehog", may be it is a integral in space-time which will give $\pm 4\pi$, because time variation of Ω(,) at each r around the hedgehog will give some solid angle, if "move once around" means summation over r around hedgehog then the whole statement will give a integral in space-time.